# Development stack to build a paid webapp with forms, save progress, multiple forms in parallel, attached documents

Tags: document-management, forms, survey, user-management

I aim to build a web app that largely relies on forms/"surveys". It would be similar to ELSTER online, the official tax tool in Germany. Probably other tax software would be similar. This means it should have at the least the following functions:

- Users can fill out complex forms/surveys.
- The forms consists of several units/pages. It is possible for a user to fill out only parts of a form and return to it later. The progress is shown (e.g., by check marks). The user can also start multiple forms before submitting one.
- Document management: Users can upload documents to support the forms, and do the usual things (view documents, delete etc.).
- User management: Users can register, have a profile and so on. Also, each user belongs to an organization, and each organization can have multiple users. There is some basic role/rights management. E.g., different users of the same organization can work on the same forms.
- Payment: Users need a subscription to use the web app and pay for it monthly.

Another point would be that development should not take too long. Great flexibility is not needed; it's just about getting a functional app.

At the moment, I am in fact considering a very simple tool stack:

- WordPress with some plugins such as JetEngine and Stripe integration
- SurveyJS for forms/surveys

But that does not seem very professional to me. Also, this approach would be rather generic and not so specific as I would like it to be (or ELSTER online is).

Do you know of a better stack, or even open source tools that come close to the app I want to build?

Comment: Why is that not "professional" when you need something quick? You definitely won't find a form-specific framework/CMS with ready integrations such as payments.